# Deep hierarchy of fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Is it possible to build up an architecture like this with fragments:

Navigation drawer showing the main menu and then when clicking one of the menu items an ordinary combo of list/detail is shown (so far so good, all tutorials explain this). But what if I want a button on the detailed fragment to show a second combo of list/detail fragments, which should not be reached through the Navigation Drawer?

As I have implemented it now, one fragment instatiates the next, which is wrong according to the guides (fragments should always communicate through an activity). But it works fine as long as the user is clicking deeper into the app. The issue comes when he starts to use navigate back, because all the UIs then start to be laid on top of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't.  Fragments aren't 100 percent consistent across all versions of Android, unless you're using the support library.  Even then-  nested fragments have always been a bit broken.  They weren't even supported at first.  The more levels of nesting you add, the less likely it is to work as expected.  I wouldn't add more than 2 levels of fragments, and I'd try hard to keep it to 0-1.